# Can minimal CNF contain clause longer than initial CNF?

Tags: boolean-algebra, normal-forms

Let $\Phi$ be a k-CNF and $\Phi_{min}$ be a minimal CNF (one that contains smallest amount of literal occurences) that is equal to $\Phi$.

Can $\Phi_{min}$ contain a clause of size $m > k$?

What I have tried:

Let's define the concept of partial assignment: an assignment that has free variables. Example: $x_1 = 0, x_2 = \{0\ ,1\}, x_3 = 1$. Here $x_2$ value remains unassigned.

If $\Phi$ contains clause $C(p)$, then $\Phi(\overline p) =0$.

Example: $\Phi = (x_1\lor x_2\lor x_3)\land (x_2\lor x_3\lor x_4)$. Here $\Phi(x_1=0,x_2=0,x_3=0)=0$.

1. Going further, if $\Phi$ is k-CNF, it means that shortest unsatisfied partial assignment has length $l\leq k$.
2. Also, formula already contains info about **all** unsatisfied partial assignments.

P.1 and p.2 says, that we don't need to use partial assignment of length $l>k$ to express the formula.

One more statement, $\Phi(p)=0\Rightarrow \Phi(p, x_i)=0$, where $x_i$ is fixed variable that is not in $p$.

Here is where I got stuck: $\Phi_{min}$ contains smallest amount of shortest inverted partial assignments of formula $\Phi$. Let's say that each of partial assignments $p_1, p_2$ has length $l$, such that $\Phi(p_1) =0, \Phi(p_2)=0$. Can we change them to one longer partial assignment $p$?

Restrictions are following: if you'll change or remove any variable in $p_1$ or $p_2$ (we'll call them $p'_1$ and $p'_2$ respectively), then $\Phi(p'_1) = 1$ and $\Phi(p'_2)=1$.

Intuitively it seems that they can't be combined, but what about logic?

Comment: Could you give one reference of "partial assignment" or is this one temporary definition for this question? By [this article](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/extras/satisfiability.html), "we can save the work of checking all *extensions* of the partial assignment. ... neither the truth assignment {p = 1, q = 0, r = 0} nor the assignment {p = 1, q = 0, r = 1} satisfies Δ" means partial assignment is something like {p = 1 , q = 0} when we have 3 variables able to be assigned values (i.e. partially assign some variables instead of all). It isn't related with "free variable".

Comment: I think that article agrees with my definition. I have removed "free variable" because, indeed, that made the description ambiguous.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question correctly. Seems easy to prove the following: "At least one variable is true" easily translates into the CNF $x_1 \vee \dots \vee x_n$ but if you restrict to $k$-CNF with $k<n$, you can easily show that you need more than $n$ literals ($x_i$ needs to appears once. If you use extra encoding variables then this will have > n literals. Otherwise, one variable needs to appear at most twice (otherwise you have clauses with disjoint variables and you can quickly show that this will not be equivalent to what you need).