# Prove or disprove that the Quine-McCluskey method generates the circuit with the minimum inputs and minimum gates?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, digital-circuits, karnaugh-map

Recently, when I self-learnt Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 8th by Kenneth Rosen, it says in 12.4 Minimization of Circuits which uses the Karnaugh Map or the Quine-McCluskey method:

> Minimizing a Boolean
> function makes it possible to construct a circuit for this function that uses the *fewest gates* and
> *fewest inputs* to the AND gates and OR gates in the circuit, among all circuits for the Boolean
> expression we are minimizing.

So I set the goal function to optimize and get the smallest value $f(x)=N_1(x)\cdot N_2(x)$ where $x$ is the target Boolean expression and $N_1(x)$ is the gate number and $N_2(x)$ is the input number in the minimized circuit although this target function seems to *not be used explicitly by any references*.

---

I have already known that the Karnaugh Map won't always "generate the circuit with the minimum inputs and minimum gates" as [QA_1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4459351/1059606) says which has $f(x)=(5+1)\cdot 4$ for the Karnaugh Map (4 AND gates and 1 OR gates. Here I assume the gate can have multiple inputs) and $f(x)=(4+1)\cdot 4$ for the Quine-McCluskey method. The problems of the Karnaugh Map in this example is that it *doesn't have all prime implicants* but the Quine-McCluskey method has all terms being prime implicants.

QA_1 links to [QA_2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4458911/1059606) (I tried search for the reference book of QA_2 based on its quote but failed) which cares about the fact that "the Quine-McCluskey method" will have only *prime implicants* left and the comment shows Adjacency and Idempotence are enough which can get Absorption. This is used in the construction process of the Quine-McCluskey method which will *only have prime implicants* at last.

Q:

Does the Quine-McCluskey method minimize $f(x)$ since it has only prime implicants?

Comment: Both algorithms find prime implicants, therefore my question is related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76922/71879 Basically, I asked if a minimum CNF can contain non-prime implicants. or if prime implicants can be longer than any original clause. A lack of answers suggests it's an open problem and therefore your question also would be open...

Comment: And if you allow the circuit to have depth over 2, then trivially this algorithm won't always produce the smallest circuits.

Comment: @rus9384 Thanks for replies. Re to the 1st comment: 1. You are right. If "a minimum CNF can contain non-prime implicants", then "the Quine-McCluskey method" won't minimize. So my question can be reduced to yours. Hope someone can make these 2 questions closed. 2. BTW, "the Karnaugh Map" *may not find all* prime implicants in some cases as the question says.

Comment: Re to the 2nd comment: Here you may define the goal function as the number of *2-ary* gates (implied in your question post "smallest amount of literal occurences") which will cause depth greater than 2 while the question assumes using gates with multiple inputs. Both are fine since I didn't find one *quantification formula* defining the size of the circuit when having one corresponding logical formula. Do you know some references showing one quantification formula?

Comment: We know that there exist depth 3 $AC^0$ circuits that can't be transformed into equally small depth 2 $AC^0$ circuits. E.g. XOR or threshold functions. So, while directly transforming a depth 2 $AC^0$ circuit would require (log depth) $NC^1$ circuit, it still would be a larger $NC^1$ circuit than the transformation of the depth 3 $AC^0$ circuit. Simply because the latter circuit reuses gate outputs more efficiently. An efficient transformation would not be different, but then Quine-McCluskey algorithm does not perform it.

Comment: @rus9384 Thanks for your comment which implies one reference about circuit complexity. I didn't read one specific book about complexity and my current knowledge only covers $O,\Theta,\Omega$, so your description about $AC^0,NC^1$ is a bit out of my reach. Could you say more readably using more basic knowledge? If that is a bit inconvenient, I will return to this question when I read one specific book about complexity.

Comment: Basically, the minimal formula that uses only AND, OR and NOT gates for $x\oplus y\oplus z$ is $(x\land(yz\lor\overline y\overline z))\lor(\overline x\land(\overline yz\lor y\overline z))$ which uses 9 fanin-2 gates. Whereas smallest CNF or DNF uses 11 gates. And Quine-McCluskey algorithm generates only DNFs or CNFs.

Comment: @rus9384 Thanks for your helpful example. Maybe you want to say $\overline{y}\;\overline{z}$ instead of $\overline{yz}$. More specifically, DNF will have $xyz\lor x\overline{y}\;\overline{z} \lor \overline{x}\overline{y}z \lor \overline{x}y\overline{z}$. As you says, it has 11 gates.